# How to get the name of the current selected Ajax Tab

Tags: jquery, tabs

iv browsed the net looking for an example on this but sadly all i can find is questions on how to recieve the index number of the selected tab, again this isnt what i want, i want the ID how can you achieve this with JQuery, Im new to Jquery so any help would be brilliant

Comment: We will need to see some HTML in order to answer this with any specificity.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the id of any jquery-element by calling `.attr('id')` on it.